# How to get the Cloud Endpoints client library autogenerated by Google Plugin for Eclipse to incorporate updates to the Entity class?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I am working on an App-Engine-connected-Android project created through Google Plugin for Eclipse. After I updated some fields and methods for one of the entity classes in the App Engine backend, I regenerated the Cloud Endpoints client library, but it still shows old methods and new ones are not being generated.

I even tried the already existing endpoint libraries in the Android project and then regenerating the client libraries through GPE - it did not work.How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the project after the changes? Some IDEs automatically save changes as you make them but you have to explicitly click on save in Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, I did save. It seems that the new ones were not showing up in the client library because they had two parameters instead of one. I am not sure why the old methods that were deleted from the App Engine project were still present in the client library, but after deleting the field itself from the Entity class in App Engine, all the related setter and getter methods disappeared from the client library also.